# Where can I find documentation or an example of a C/C++ Plugin for FSX

Tags: c++, simulations

I want to make a plugin for FSX in C/C++ but all the examples and documentation forward to the SimConnect Examples for FSX.

I want to access USB-hardware from the plugin and for this reason I'm looking for a way to write a plugin in C/C++ which does not rely on the SimConnect interface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps you with FSX, however documentation for FS2004 modules has always been rare too, so this might be of help.

Here's an example of an FS2004 module: http://pastebin.com/AQG2H0Vc (written by myself, public domain). From my experience the APIs haven't changed that much so with a bit of luck you'll be able to adopt the example for FSX.

Important is the *Linkage* global variable (type *GAUGESLINKAGE*) because it includes the MSFS version (*0x900* in the example) and callback functions that MSFS shall call. I don't remember exactly what *ImportTable* was for, however if you're not writing code for gauges, you may just ignore it for now.

Have you checked the SDK that is shipped with the FSX Pro/Deluxe edition?

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, I will try to create a plugin for FSX with it.